# Getting a No parameterless constructor defined for this object when using HttpServerUtilityWrapper in action method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

this is my controller class, i have passed the httpserverutility class an an argument because i am using it in my service layer

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RegisterAuthor([Bind(Include = "Name,Surname,Email,Password")] Author author, HttpPostedFileWrapper file, HttpServerUtilityWrapper server)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _accountService.RegisterAuthor(author, file, server);

                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            return View(author);
        }
```

this is my service layer - however i get a [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper'.] ?

```
public Author RegisterAuthor(Author author, HttpPostedFileWrapper file, HttpServerUtilityWrapper server)
        {

            var imageName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var img = "profile-img";
            var imageFormatName = $"{author.AuthorID}-{img}-{imageName}";

            var imagesPath = Path.Combine(server.MapPath("~/Images/Authors/"), imageFormatName);
            file.SaveAs(imagesPath);

            author.ProfileImage = imageFormatName;



            _topBloggersDb.Authors.Add(author);
            _topBloggersDb.SaveChanges();

            return author;
        }
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to hand over the server path to the service call? Should make your life easier...

Comment: the question is why am i getting this error if i am passing the utility wrapper in the arguments to give me access to httpserver?

Comment: If you are using UnityConfig, then did you registered types in UnityConfig.cs file?